# How can I do this program to show the typed number as many times as the value of the number?

Tags: c++

I have to write this program and till now this is what I have.
The program need to read a number from the user and then to show number from 1 to n(typed number from user) as many times as the value of the typed number.
For example : If user types 4 the output should be 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4.

Please can someone help?

```
int main (){
int nr, i;
cout<<"Type a number: ";
cin>>nr;
for(i=1; i<=nr; i++) {
cout<<i;
if(nr>=i) {
cout<<i;
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two loops. The inner loop goes from 0 to i and writes `i`. The outer one is correct already.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    unsigned int num;

    std::cout << "Type a number: ";
    std::cin >> num;

    for (unsigned int loop = 1; loop <= num; loop++)
    {
        for (unsigned int loop2 = 0; loop2 < loop; loop2++)
        {
            std::cout << loop << ' ';
        }
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: did the explanation although it was a simple one.

Comment: Good job for that and I +1 for this. Remember there are always new learners to everything, so no matter how simple it is, it's always recommended to accompany your answer with proper explanation, instead of leaving a plain solution.

Comment: thanks a lot for that , will always remember that